# ChangeFileModeByMask error (5): Access is denied

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, etl

I accessed MySQL database and fetched the table. 
Everything is working fine till that.

when i am trying to save the records in text or other formats i am getting the error 
 **Exit Code Exception exit Code=1: 'Change File Mode By Mask error' (5): Access is denied.**

Any help will be appreciated.

```
object jdbcConnect {
 def main(args: Array[String]) {

   val url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydb" 
   val username = "root"
   val password = "token_password"
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance


   //DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());

   val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JDB CRDD").setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val myRDD = new JdbcRDD( sc, () => 
    DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password) ,
  "select s_Id,issue_date from store_details limit ?, ?",
  0, 10, 1, r => r.getString("s_Id") + ", " + r.getString("issue_date"))

   myRDD.foreach(println)
   myRDD.saveAsTextFile("C:/jdbcrddexamplee")

  }
}
```

Error

> 17/07/18 11:10:19 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 2.0
>   (TID 2) ExitCodeException exitCode=1: ChangeFileModeByMask error (5):
>   Access is denied.
>
> at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:582)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:479)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:773)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:866)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:849)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:733)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.(RawLocalFileSystem.java:225)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)

Comment: have you tried writing in other different location?

Comment: Yep... I have tried that but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed to be a permission error. My foolishness...

Make sure to run anything as an admin. Though i will suggest to use dataframe instead of RDD :D